# binding multiple sites to one site - programmatically - iis 7

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, iis-7

I have different websites (more than 300) www.ca1.com, www.ca2.com. I would like bind all these sites to my main site - www.myMainsite.com programmatically. Can you help me in solving this. thanks.

Original post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007548/binding-different-dns-to-one-dns-iis-7-programmatically/8007942#8007942

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like, you can leverage PowerShell's [Set-WebConfiguration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee807820.aspx) interface to configure a defined [system.webserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689429(VS.90).aspx) object, will handle the task of configuring URL Redirection for that defined object:

Where:

- `\sites\Default Web Site` is your site.
- `domain.com` is your destination

  ```
  Set-WebConfiguration system.webServer/httpRedirect "IIS:\sites\Default Web Site" -Value @{enabled="true";destination="domain.com";exactDestination="true";httpResponseStatus="Permanent"}
  ```

I'm sure there are further interfaces to the IIS config, but this is likely the easiest one.